# How can I get the Gmail contact of my account in my .NET application?

Tags: asp.net

How can I get the [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) contact of my account in ASP.NET. Is there some code to import the Gmail contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Gmail Agent API](http://johnvey.com/features/gmailapi/)

Answer (score 2):

Google provides an API for all of its applications, so you can use the provided *[Gmail Agent API](http://johnvey.com/features/gmailapi/)* to load contacts.